# UI doesn't fully update when receive bloc informations

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc

I have this weird problem: I want to update a grid of items when I click on it. I use a BLoC pattern to manage the changement so the view just receive a list and have to display it. My problem is that the view doesn't fully update.

Before I go further in the explanation, here my code

```
body: BlocEventStateBuilder<ShopEvent, ShopState>(
  bloc: bloc,
  builder: (BuildContext context, ShopState state) {
    staggeredTile.clear();
    cards.clear();

    staggeredTile.add(StaggeredTile.count(4, 0.1));
    cards.add(Container());

    if (state.products != null) {
      state.products.forEach((item) {
        staggeredTile.add(StaggeredTile.count(2, 2));
        cards.add(
          Card(
            child: InkWell(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.network(
                    item.picture,
                    height: 140,
                  ),
                  Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0)),
                  Text(item.title)
                ],
              ),
              onTap: () {
                bloc.emitEvent(ClickShopEvent(item.id));
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
    });
  }
  return StaggeredGridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 4,
    staggeredTiles: staggeredTile,
    children: cards,
  );
}),
```

So, I have two items. When I click on the first one, I'm suppose to have one item with a different name and picture. But when I click, I have one item as expected, but with the same text and image. When I print thoses values, it's correctly updated but the view doesn't show it.

Do you have any clues of my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reason that I can't explain, when I replaced

```
staggeredTile.clear();
cards.clear();
```

by

```
staggeredTile = new List<StaggeredTile>();
cards = new List<Widget>();
```

It works fine.

If someone can explain me the reason, I'd be gratefull.

Comment: I think it is because the BlocBuilder monitors the state, but in the state you only have a reference to the list. When you're doing List.clear(), you're changing the list, but not the reference and the builder does not record that as a change.

When you assign a new object to it however, it does record the change and rebuilds the UI.